# Laravel, add an existing entity to an entity collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am tryng to add an existing entity to an entity collection like

```php
$entity->collection->push(Entity::where('field', 'value')->first());
[...]
// When I log $entity I see the new entity in $entity->collection
$entity->save();
// But nothing on database
```

Do you have a clue on why it's not saving the entity ?

Answer (score 0):

**HasMany case**

Assuming `$entity` is instance of Eloquent and `collection` is magic property representing `hasMany` relation, so you have something like:

```php
class Entity extends Model 
{
//...
    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Entity:class);
    }
//...
}
```

then `collection` is only short way to access `$entity->collection()->get()`, so it can not be used to mutate DB.

Instead you can call

```php
$entity->collection()->save(
    Entity::where('field', 'value')->first()
);
```

according to https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html#method_save

**BelongsToMany**

Many-to-many relation has method `attach`, which accepts key of related record as fist argument:

```php
$entity->collection()->save(
    //assume relation is built by primary key
    Entity::where('field', 'value')->first()->getKey()
);
```

Complete documentation is here - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: My collection is a `BelongsToMany`. So I tryed as you suggested `$entity->collection()->save(Entity::where('field', 'value')->first());`

Comment: In that case you can use `->attach($id)`. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `BelongsToMany`, this is a important bit of information.

You can read more about managing Many-to-Many relations in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

But in short you want to use `->attach($entity)`.

So your code should be:

```php
$entity->collection()->attach(
    Entity::where('field', 'value')->first()->getKey()
);
```

`save` doesn't work because the entity already exists and should only used to save new entities to that database and attach them to the relation at the same time.